# Cannot get suggested enum value

Tags: python, enums, pydev

I'm studying about Python using pyDev and realized that when I have an `Enum` and want to use a value of it, pyDev does not suggest which value to use. For example:

```
weapon = Enum("Weapon", "sword hammer axe")

print(weapon.sword)
```

it does not suggest `sword` after `weapon.`, and neither other values. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using the more usual `Enum` syntax (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html))? PyDev may not be parsing the argument strings.

Comment: Like jon said, the Enum class is probably a better choice, and more similar to the Java syntax you are accustomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I found what I wanted in [enum documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#autonumber).
Having a AutoNumber class that extends Enum and numerates automatically overriding **new**().

```
class AutoNumber(Enum):

    def __new__(cls):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

class Color(AutoNumber):
    red = ()
    green = ()
    blue = ()

print (Color.green.value == 2)
>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

For the short-term use the [class syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

For the long-term ask the PyDev folks to support the `Enum()` style.